# How to use Silverlight objects in web service?

Tags: silverlight, web-services

I'm developing a web application that is supposed to display a HUGE amount of vector data using Silverlight on client side. Imagine something like google maps but using vector graphics only, so DeepZoom is not an option.

I was planning to generate a huge XAML in web service and then return only small regions to clients using built-in SL `Clip` and `VisualTreeHelper` methods. The problem is that I'm unable to instantiate Silverlight objects (e.g. Canvas) inside web service!

Of course I can create XAML strings programmatically, but I'm losing SL clipping capabilities and code becomes much harder to create and maintain.

Answer (score 0):

I found a temporary workaround: Silverlight objects can be created in another thread with `ApartmentState.STA` option set. But it raises more problems with inter-thread communication and multiple user requests, so I cannot mark this as final answer.